# hide and show div file (logged in)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How I can hide this - "`<div class="show1">`" when user are not logged in and show only when user are logged in?

This is my code --->>>

```
   <html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>100% | Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main/home.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main/register.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script></head><body><div id="container">
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <br/><br/><div class="show1">TEXT</div><div class="show1">TEXT</div>
    <div class="hidden1"><div class="right-login" id="container-login"><div id="palabi5px">
    <form method="post" class="formpost" id="nonono">
        <input type="text" class="username" name="username0" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="password" class="password" name="password0" placeholder="********">        
        <button type="submit" name="login" class="loging">Login</button>
    </form>
    ---------------------------------
    <br/><br/>
    Text!<br/><br/>
    <br/>
    ---------------------------------
    <br/><br/></div></div></div>
    <?php include 'saites.php'; ?></body></html>

<?php 
session_start();
require('connect.php');
$username0 = @$_POST['username0'];
$password0 = @$_POST['password0'];

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if($username0 && $password0) {
    $check = mysqli_query($connect," SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username0."'");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($check);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($check) != 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check)){
                $db_username0 = $row['username'];   
                $db_password0 = $row['password'];
            }
            if($username0 == $db_username0 && ($password0) == $db_password0){
                @$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                $(document).ready(function(){    
                    alert('page loaded');  // alert to confirm the page is loaded    
                    $('.hidden1').hide(); //enter the class or id of the particular html element which you wish to hide. 
                    $('.show1').show(); //SHOW
                });
                </script>";
            }else{
                echo "<script>{ alert('Your pass id wrong.');}</script>";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script>{ alert('Couldn't find username.');}</script>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "<script>{ alert('Please fill in all the fields.');}</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: use the session id to check whether the user logged in

Comment: I'm no php expert, but to me it looks like you're at risk of a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Please check out http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php security is more important.

Comment: I don't know what you are going to show inside that div for logged-in users but you shoud probably do that in PHP not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="show1">TEXT</div><div class="show1">TEXT</div>
```

Replace with  following code

```
   if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
        echo '<div class="show1">TEXT</div><div class="show1">TEXT</div>';
    }
```